# How to get data from the 5th cell in a html table row using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have code that works fine:

```
var myValue = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('td:first').text();
```

is there anyway to get something like this working as the below code DOESN"T work:

```
var myValue2 = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('td:fifth').text();
```

as you can see I am trying to get the 5th column in the row.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
var myValue2 = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('td:eq(4)').text();
```

If `$(this)` refers to an element within the same row as the cells you are trying to select, you can shorten it slightly, using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
var myValue2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(4)').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, `:first` is a shortcut for `:eq(0)`; there is no pseudo-class named `:fifth`. You might be able to do something like:

```
var myValue2 = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('td:nth-child(5)').text();
```

And I think you can combine the two:

```
var myValue3 = $(this).parents('tr:first td:nth-child(5)').text();
```